# What does the return True mean in this hash map?

Tags: python, data-structures

```
def add(self, key, value):
    key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
    key_value = [key, value]

    if self.map[key_hash] is None:
        self.map[key_hash] = list([key_value])
        return True
    else:
        for pair in self.map[key_hash]:
            if pair[0] == key:
                pair[1] = value
                return True
        self.map[key_hash].append(key_value)
        return True
```

When the code above says return True after `pair[1] = value` and at the end of the code at the bottom of `self.map[key_hash].append(key_value)` what is this meant to do? How does it effect the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you arrive on `return True` rest of your function don't run. in the above code when `return True` after `"pair[1] = value"` rest of code don't run.
like this code:

```
def add(...):
    bol_return = False
    ...

    if .... is None:
        ...
        bol_return = True
    else:
        for ...:
            if ...:
                ...
                bol_return = True
        ....
        return bol_return
```

Comment: in this case the rest of the code doesn't run anyway because of the if-else block and `return True` could be just once at the end of the function

Comment: This might be a stupid question..... but if it said "return False" instead, would the code also end?

Comment: @StudentProgrammer12, yes when you arrive on return function is ending

Comment: you can define variable and store True or False in it and end of function return true or False. I edit answer and send example for you now

Comment: Ahhh, the way you put it is what I always see when coding. That's what I'm used to thank you so much for this example!